# Add required Validate property only for Mandatory ids not for Optional ids of a property

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a List viewmodel named **Answers**, which has the following properties :

```
public int AnswerId
public string Answer
public bool IsOptional
```

Now for a form submit in MVC, if I assign **[Required]** attribute for Answer, it will make every ids of the Answer property required. So is there any way that if "IsOptional" is true for an AnswerId, the validation will not work for the optional answer but work only for mandatory AnswerId ? Do I need to create a custom validation attribute ? .. please guide me

Comment: You could also check server side. If (condition) ModelState.Add(...)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you try the very good [ExpressiveAnnotations Nuget package](https://github.com/jwaliszko/ExpressiveAnnotations). It provides custom validation attributes that totally fit your need. This way, you could make the `Answer` member required only when `IsOptional` is set to false.

```cs
using ExpressiveAnnotations.Attributes;

public int AnswerId { get; set; }

[RequiredIf(nameof(IsOptional) + " == false")]
public string Answer { get; set; }

public bool IsOptional { get; set; }
```